# What is the reason for the blood between Henry and Clair in The Time Traveler's Wife?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-time-travelers-wife

There is a scene after the miscarriage where Henry and his wife are sleeping on their bed and they see blood on the bed.

What does it mean?  Is this a second miscarriage or did I miss something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My understanding is that yes, it was a second "miscarriage". Although not a traditional miscarriage, but rather the fetus had time-traveled, which of course lead to the unborn baby's death, as it could not survive outside the mother's womb.